# RECUPERAR EL PERFIL DEL USUARIO AL INICIAR LA SESION EN C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

estoy trabajando con C# en 4Capas y estoy teniendo dificultad de recuperar el perfil del usuario desde la base de datos (SQL Server) y mostrar en el menú. En la Capa Datos es donde tengo el error y es como sigue:

```
public bool IniciarSesion(string username, string password)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPINICIARSESION", conexion)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            conexion.Open();

            //ENVIAMOS LOS PARAMETROS
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USUARIO", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRASEÑA", password);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    E_InicioSesion.IdUsuarios = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    E_InicioSesion.Codigo = reader.GetString(1);
                    E_InicioSesion.Nombres = reader.GetString(2);
                    E_InicioSesion.Apellidos = reader.GetString(3);
                    E_InicioSesion.Usuario = reader.GetString(4);
                    E_InicioSesion.Contraseña = reader.GetString(5);
                    E_InicioSesion.Email = reader.GetString(6);
                    E_InicioSesion.TiposUsuario = reader.GetString(7);
                    E_InicioSesion.Perfil = reader.GetByte(8); //Aquí es donde sale el error, no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo byte en byte[]
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

He buscado como solucionar el error pero no he encontrado nada, si por favor pueden ayudar, gracias.!

Comment: Hola, has probado a emplear el Método `reader.GetBytes()` (acabado en s)?

Comment: prueba asi  E_InicioSesion.Perfil =(byte[]) reader[8];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo puse la linea que te puse en comentarios.

```
  while (reader.Read())
            {
                E_InicioSesion.IdUsuarios = reader.GetInt32(0);
                E_InicioSesion.Codigo = reader.GetString(1);
                E_InicioSesion.Nombres = reader.GetString(2);
                E_InicioSesion.Apellidos = reader.GetString(3);
                E_InicioSesion.Usuario = reader.GetString(4);
                E_InicioSesion.Contraseña = reader.GetString(5);
                E_InicioSesion.Email = reader.GetString(6);
                E_InicioSesion.TiposUsuario = reader.GetString(7);
                E_InicioSesion.Perfil =(byte[])reader[8]; //antepones (byte[])               
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió tu respuesta!